# Hotkey reassigning macro not working

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I am using AutoHotkey to re-assign some hotkeys in Dr. Explain. The macro executes to the point of the message but the actual new hotkeys aren't working.

Here's the script:

```
WinActivate, DRAFT_Complete Jazzit Help Masterfile* - Dr.Explain (Licensed to: Accountants Templates Inc.)

MsgBox Normal --> Alt + A and Normal - emphasis --> Alt + S

Return

;Change keystrokes for normal and normal-emphasis

#Inputlevel 1
^+n::!a
^+6::!s
#Inputlevel 1

#IfWinActive
```

Not sure if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Defines hotkeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> for windows containing "Jazzit" in their title**

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2     ; All #If statements match anywhere in title

#IfWinActive Jazzit
F1:: MsgBox Normal --> Alt + A and Normal - emphasis --> Alt + S
^+n::send !a
^+6::send !s
#IfWinActive
```

**The remapping format (i.e., not using `send`) passes along all modifier keys:**

```
^+n::!a     ; sends Alt+Shift+Ctrl+A
^+6::!s     ; sends Alt+Shift+Ctrl+6
```

Comment: I tried moved the hotkeys. See code `WinActivate, DRAFT_Complete Jazzit Help Masterfile* - Dr.Explain (Licensed to: Accountants Templates Inc.)

MsgBox Normal --> Alt + A and Normal - emphasis --> Alt + S

#Inputlevel 1
^+n::!a
^+6::!s
#Inputlevel 1

;Change keystrokes for normal and normal-emphasis


#IfWinActive` It still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but still no luck. I'm at a loss. Perhaps the software is blocking the change? It's ok, I'll revert to manual. Much appreciated!

Comment: Try sendraw, sendinput, sendPlay or sendevent, instead of send